# Rotate the moon around the earth JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I was creating a simple Solar System. The earth rotates around the sun. Now I am struggling while trying to rotate the moon around earth, in the same time while earth rotates around sun.
Thank you for your help!
The earth code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Earth extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Timer t=new Timer(100,this);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Color color;
    double angle;
    
    public Planetet(int x,int y,int height,int width,Color color) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.height=height;
    this.width=width;
    this.color=color;}
        
    
    
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
            //Extra Code for Screen clearing
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            boolean rotation=true;

            int a, b;
            if (rotation) {
                int width = getWidth();
                int height = getHeight();
                a = (int) (Math.cos(angle) * (width / 3) + (width / 2));
                b = (int) (Math.sin(angle) * (height / 3) + (height / 2));
            } else {
                a = getWidth()/2 - gjatsia/2;
                b = getHeight()/2 - gjersia/2;
            }

            g.setColor(ngjyra);
            g.fillOval(a, b, gjatsia, gjersia);
            t.start();
        }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        angle+=0.1/2;
        if (angle>(2*Math.PI))
        angle=0.1;
        repaint();}
        
    
    
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        JFrame MainFrame=new JFrame();
        MainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.black );
        MainFrame.setSize(600,600);
        Sun sun=new Sun(250,250,50,50,Color.YELLOW);
        Earth earth=new Earth(400,270,20,20,Color.blue);
        Moon moon=new Moon(400,270,10,10,Color.GRAY);

        MainFrame.add(sun);
        MainFrame.setVisible(true);

        MainFrame.add(earth);

        MainFrame.setVisible(true);
        MainFrame.add(moon);

        MainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }



    

}
```

The sun code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Sun extends JComponent{
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Color color;
    double angle;
    
    public Sun(int x,int y,int height,int width,Color color) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.height=height;
    this.width=width;
    this.color=color;}
        
    
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        

        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, height, width);
    }}
```

The Moon code (which needs corrections):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Moon extends JComponent implements ActionListener{
    Timer t=new Timer(100,this);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Color color;
    double angle;

    public Moon(int x,int y,int height,int width,Color color) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.height=height;
    this.width=width;
    this.color=color;}

    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int width =getWidth();
        int height=getHeight();
         int a = (int) (Math.cos(angle) * (width/6) + (width/4));
         int b = (int) (Math.sin(angle) * (height/6) + (height/4));

        g.setColor(ngjyra);
        g.fillOval(a, b, gjatsia, gjersia);
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        angle-=0.5/2;
        if (angle>(2*Math.PI))
        angle=0.0;
        repaint();}}
```

[So this is the output. The earth and the moon both rotate on its own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKgNJ.png)

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works.  We will not finish your homework for you. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not my homework, but any help would be welcomed. Btw thanks for the advice!

Comment: Sorry, but there are several other nearly identical questions posted in the last day.  That strongly implies that this is a class assignment and several people have come here to get someone to write the code for them.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ah okay. I was just trying to get help on the idea of how to connect the moon with the earth and rotate around it!!

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: everything rotates around something - A rotates around B - and B rotates around C - C rotates around D... How can you represent this relationship in code? Perhaps by giving each object a reference to the thing it rotates around...

Also - if you have multiple objects that have the same, or very similar behavior - you can abstract this behavior away to a parent (or abstract) class - which saves you from writing the same code multiple times.

Hope that helps you to think about your code.